# Why does Google Analytics miss Yandex clicks?

Tags: google-analytics, yandex

Google Analytics seems to miss most of the clicks from Yandex. Is there anything to make them show up in Google Analytics?

Comment: By "miss" them you mean that the clicks don't get counted as "Organic Search" but rather appear in the "Referrals" report?

Comment: It does not get accounted at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately** Yandex is not one of the Default Search Engines in Googles list.

**Fortunately** there is a way to add Yanex and get the correct results.

---

**Change your organic search traffic settings**

This setting is managed in the admin settings of each property in your account. To add, edit, reorder, or remove search engines:

1. Navigate to a property. If you're not in the settings menu, click
   Admin. Select the account and property you want to edit.
2. From the property column, click Tracking Info then Organic Search
   Sources.
3. Click +Add Search Engine.
4. In the form, specify what the Domain Name Contains and the Query
   Parameter. You can also specify a Search Engine Name and what the
   Path Contains.
5. Click Create

Click edit or delete to change or remove a search engine you’ve already added. To reorder the list, drag and drop the order of each row by using the mouse to grab the dots left of the search engine name.

You can learn more about it on Google's page : [Customize organic search sources](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795821?hl=en#searchEngine)

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics does track Yandex.   It does not track it as search engine traffic, it reports it as referral traffic.  Here is a screenshot of the Acquisition Referrals report for a Russian site.   It shows Yandex as referrer #4:

[image]
norcal johnny already posted a good answer about how to get GA to report it as organic search engine traffic instead.

Comment: The weird thing is that I don't see them as referral as well, but I know that I get clicks from Yandex through server logs.

Comment: Have you looked through multiple pages of the referrers?   If it is just a couple in the server log, it might be from users that don't have JavaScript enabled or who have GA tracking blocked or disabled.    You could also have a filter applied to your GA account that is discarding some data.   Check to make sure there isn't a faulty filter.

Comment: I checked my analytics without filters as well. The issue does not stem from them. The funny thing is, GA recognizes Yandex related traffic without "ru" TLD.